# Python doesn't want to run function asynchronous

Tags: python, asynchronous

I just want to run async function like really async, but it blocks main thread for 5 seconds

```
import asyncio

async def sideTask():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)  # this will pause main thread for no reason
    print("doing side job")

global test

test = 0

# main work
while True:
    test += 1

    time.sleep(1)
    if test > 3:
        test = 0
        asyncio.run(sideTask())
```

I am expecting async function being async

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by running sideTask() in the loop?
If you're trying to see output of "doing side job" while asyncio.sleep(5) is executing, you should simply put "doing side job" before asyncio.sleep(5)
asyncio.sleep() is not pausing the main thread, you are just doing sleep function which serves no purpose and makes it look like it's not functioning in the main time.

Comment: while True stops workings for 5 seconds, i dont want asyncio.run(sideTask()) call to stop while True loop